# Pandas/Python: How can I filter a Dataframe or Series by using functions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have a Dataframe df with among others the columns "Age" and "Name" in my Jupyter Notebook

Usually, when I just want entries fulfilling certian criteria, I filter e.g. by

`df[df["Age"]>20]`

meaning "df where `df["Age"]` happens to be above 20 and therefore it shows only the entries of the df where age is above 20

Now I want to get only the entries where the Name contains "Alex"

```
df[df["Name"].find("Alex")>-1]         #(".find" returns -1 if Alex is not in in the checked string)
```

Acutually this does not work seemingly because this function gets applied to the whole series, which is obviously nonsense and therefore gives an error.
I would not have expected this behavior because `df["Age"]>20` in the first example also worked (meaning it got applied to every single cell of "Age" and not to the series itself). Any ideas how I fix this?

Yours sincerely :)

Comment: Can you try this one ... df[df["Name"]=="Alex"]

Answer (score 1):

```
alex_df = df[df['Name'] == 'Alex']
```

If you have multiple names you can use the following.:

```
name_list = ['Alex', 'Sam', 'Donna']

names_df = df[df['Name'].isin(name_list)]
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to filter by cells, where the name contains alex. this would only work if the name was just "Alex", wouldn't it? So if someones name is "Alex Smith" this solution would not work

Answer (score 0):

Searching for rows where column `Name`contains `Alex` as a substring is probably easiest with pandas string accessors:

```
df[df["Name"].str.contains("Alex")]
```

More details can be found in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) of pandas.

Comment: thanks! That works fine
Note for future readers: Set regex to False, otherwise it will ignoere characters like "." or " "